# Why the correct plot of a $x(t)$ signal is $2r(t-1) - 2r(t-3) - 4u(t-3)$ and not $4r(t-1) + 4u(t-3)$

Tags: signal-processing

I'm new with this kind of mathematics and I would like to know why this graph is
 represented by

$x(t)=2r(t-1) - 2r(t-3) -4u(t-3)$

[image]

if I were to represent the signal above with basic functions (**unit step** and **unit ramp** functions) I would say that the signal $x(t)$ is $x(t)=4r(t-1)+4u(t-3)$ but **is wrong** and I can't understand why.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your definition of $r(t)$? I would expect $r(t)=\max(0,t)$ or $r(t)=\min(1,\max(0,t))$, but that does not fit either variant. The ramp function in that case is continuous, while the step function has a jump. Their non-trivial combination should have a jump at $t=3$, which the graph does not show.

Comment: $r(t)=t$ when $t>0$ and $r(t)=0$ when $t<0$

Comment: This is $r(t)=\max(0,t)$, as said, a continuous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the unit ramp can also be defined as $r(t)=t \, u(t)$, then $r(t-1)=0$ at $t=0$ and $r(t-1) = 2$ at $t=3$, then the term $2r(t-1)$ correctly reproduce the signal up to $t=3$.

Thereafter, that term would continue to "ramp-up": to stop it and make it constant at the value of $4$, from $t=3$ onwards, you shall deduct $2r(t-3)$.

So your graph is $2r(t-1)-2r(t-3)$.

If you deduct also the term $4u(t-3)$ you are bringing the signal to $0$ (for $3 \le t$) which is not what you draw.

Comment: So $-4u(t-3)$ should bring the signal down to 0? for $3 \le t$?

Comment: why is it not necessary to mention the $u(t)$?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis: with the first term you establish the ramp; deducting the second ramp, you block the signal at the value($4$) it has reached  at $t=3$;deducting  a constant signal of $4$ from $t=3$ you clearly bring the whole signal to $0$. If you make a simple sketch of the ramps and Heaviside functions involved you can easily see that.